# Angular ng show correctly switching to false / true but not hiding / showing

Tags: angularjs

Working on a follow feature and using this as the two buttons:

```
<button ng-show="{{project[0].is_following.length > 0}}"
    class="button button-block button-balanced"
    ng-click="followProject()"
    type="submit">UnFollow
</button>
<button ng-show="{{project[0].is_following.length === 0}}"
    class="button button-block button-dark"
    ng-click="followProject()"
    type="submit">Follow
</button>
```

On my API doing what It needs to, I can see the buttons switching between ng-show="true" and ng-show="false" as I follow / unfollow they switch between the buttons.

However, the buttons themselves do not hide / show. They just stay the same.

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are printing the value out of your expression. `ng-show` needs the expression itself. Try this:

```
<button ng-show="project[0].is_following.length > 0"
   class="button button-block button-balanced"
   ng-click="followProject()"
   type="submit">UnFollow
</button>
<button ng-show="project[0].is_following.length === 0"
   class="button button-block button-dark"
   ng-click="followProject()"
   type="submit">Follow
</button>
```

Comment: Makes sense to me :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-show` and `ng-hide` take *Angular expressions*. This means you don't need the {{curly braces}}.

Remove them and it will be fine.

#### So what's the difference?

The curly braces are used in Angular to do *string interpolation* - placing the value of some scope expression inside a string. So if something is expecting a string, such as in HTML or where an attribute value is treated as a string, then you use the {{curly brackets}}. Otherwise, if you are specifying a condition or expression which shouldn't be treated as a string, you should not use the curly brackets.